# Problem with qedhere

Tags: amsmath, theorems, amsthm

In a paper I'm writing, I end a proof with a displayed equation that has some cases in it.  The relevant code looks something like the following:

```
\[f(x) = \begin{cases}
2x & \text{if $x<0$}\\
7  & \text{if $x=0$}\\
1-x & \text{if $x>0$}
\end{cases} \]
\end{proof}
```

What I want to happen is for the amsthm "tombstone" to be placed on the right-hand side of the page aligned with the "1-x" line.  I think this should be possible by placing a `\qedhere` in an appropriate place, but I can't seem to figure out where (I've tried all the obvious choices, and they all give me incorrect behavior).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This can be achieved using the [`ntheorem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ntheorem) package. This package handles endmarks properly. Note, you should specify the `amsmath` and `amsthm` options if you use amsmath and the `proof`environment, further `thmmarks` to get endmarks.

Here's a complete example, placing the qed symbol at the same height like `1-x`, like desired by you:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[amsmath,amsthm,thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
\[ f(x) = \begin{cases}
     2x & \text{if $x<0$}\\
     7  & \text{if $x=0$}\\
    1-x & \text{if $x>0$}
\end{cases} \]
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

You could use further features of `ntheorem` to customize the proof layout and to choose a qed symbol. The [ntheorem documentation](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/ntheorem/ntheorem.pdf) may tell you more.

Comment: this is definitely a minor quibble; however, the bottom of the "tombstone" should really be aligned with the baseline of the last `cases` line, not with the tippy tail end of the brace.  (on the other hand, with `amsthm` and `\qedhere`, it sits on the baseline with the `$f(x)$`, so i apologize for casting stones.)

Comment: Unfortunately, the ntheorem package doesn't work with the amsart class.