# How should one format a proof inside a proof, or 'inner proof'

Tags: theorems

I've come across this a few times and have yet to find a general consensus on how to format a proof inside of a proof. Should there be a proof environment within the proof environment that is indented? Should there be a different QED.

[This thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24896/sectioning-paragraphs-such-as-for-different-cases-inside-a-proof) somewhat talks about an approach, but cases are a bit different that "inner proofs".

I checked AMS' Mathematics in Type but it had no mention of such a scenario.

Comment: Is this a TeX question? Or is it really better suited to Maths SE? That is, is it about how to typeset something - perhaps you could provide an example of the desired output - or is it about what the something should look like?

Comment: I suppose it could be either or, but I reasoned that it is best suited for TeX since it relates more to typesetting than it does computation. Also, if there is a standard way, it would be defined by AMS (or another society) and would likely be included in a TeX package. I have no example because I'm unsure of what the convention is.

Comment: I just thought that Maths SE might be more likely to know what the convention is (or if there isn't one). Just in terms of density of mathematicians.

Comment: This is off topic for this site, but how about using *lemmas* to build your proof? I think it would be best to give your readers bite-sized, easy-to-follow results, and then combine them together to make your point. You could use several `lemma` environments outside your main proof; no need for too much nesting.

Comment: i've changed the tag from `amsmath` to `theorems` -- `amsmath` deals mainly with the formatting of display math; it has nothing to do with theorems.  and i used a more generic tag than `amsthm` since there are several available theorem packages.  however, the topic is still better suited to the math se.  (the ams doesn't have a specified format for this situation.  i've seen proofs "discontinued", other material including proofs inserted, and finally the original proof completed; but there wasn't any indentation, just explanatory prose and a final tombstone.)