# Align proof tombstone with itemize/enumerate/align

Tags: align, enumerate, itemize, proof-package

When using an `itemize`/`enumerate`/`align` environment inside of a `proof` environment, the tombstone is awkwardly placed on the line *below* the end of the final line. What is the cleanest way to get the tombstone placed in-line?

i.e., the source might be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
  These are the steps. 
  \begin{itemize}
    \item $1+1=2$. 
    \item $2+2\neq5$. 
  \end{itemize}
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

but I would want it to look more like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\noindent {\em Proof.} These are the steps. 
\begin{itemize}
  \item $1+1=2$. 
  \item $2+2\neq5$. \hfill $\square$
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

but of course without having to kludgily write `\hfill` etc., and with all the spacing benefits.

I've seen some questions on here addressing similar issues, but nothing that exactly handles this (e.g. [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386315/173176)'s `unskip` doesn't seem to work, and `qedhere` seems to present its own host of issues that need to be handled manually). Apologies in advance if I overlooked a functional answer.

Comment: Please always post full but minimal examples that others can copy and test as is. Not these sniplets where we have to add stuff in order to test it. Note that this can be done using the `ntheorem` package and defining the `proof` env with a `nonumber` style. More details are in the `ntheorem` manual.

Comment: I've never found problems with `\qedhere`.

Comment: @daleif Sorry about that, I've added snippets that compile on their own. But I think `ntheorem` might do what I need, thanks!