# Problem with ntheorem, align and \qedhere

Tags: align, ntheorem

I would like to use the `align` environment inside a proof with `ntheorem`, but I have trouble with `\qedhere`.

I was guided by this (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2280/30325) code, and replaced `\[` by `align` - please consider this:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[amsmath,amsthm,thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\begin{document}

\begin{proof}   
\begin{align*}
   f(x) & = 1 \\
        & = \frac{22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222}{22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222} 
\end{align*}
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}  
\[\frac{22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222}{22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222}\] 
\end{proof}  

\end{document}
```

which gives [image]

In the `align` example, `\qedhere` is placed a bit too high. How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If manual correction is acceptable...

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[amsmath,amsthm,thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\begin{document}

\begin{proof}   
\begin{align*}
   f(x) & = 1 \\
        & = \frac{22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222}{22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222}\\[-\baselineskip]
\end{align*}
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}  
\[f(x)=\frac{22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222}{22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222}\] 
\end{proof}  

\end{document}
```

[image]