# How align the qedsymbol after of a big formula in display mode?

Tags: vertical-alignment, amsthm

### Description of the problem

My problem is this. For the proof of a math theorem i use the `proof` environment of the package `amsthm`. It adds a `\qedsymbol` in the last line of the proof, but if the proof ends with a displayed formula the *qedsymbol* appears in the next line leaving an unwanted blank space.

The documentation of [`amsthm`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/amscls/amsthdoc.pdf) teaches to fix this problem placing the command `\qedhere` after of the *displayed formula* but inside of the *appropriate environment*.

This works well if the formula is of one line like

```
\[ax^2+bx+c=0.\qedhere
\]
```

but if the proof ends in a `matrix`, or `cases` with a "*great height*" the `qedsymbol` is fixed in the **baseline** at right and it this looks higher than expected (for my taste).

The result is showed in this

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[width=7cm]{geometry} % Only for reducing space in this MWE 
\usepackage{amsmath} % For `bmatrix`
\usepackage{amsthm} % For `proof` environment
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
And this proof ends with
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}.\qedhere
\]
\end{proof}
\noindent Text
\end{document}
```

that produces

[image]

### What I want

I'd like something like

[image]

with the `qedsymbol` aligned with the *bottom* of the `matrix`. Is this possible?

Comment: This is a known issue that is fixed by the `ntheorem` package: see [problem with qedhere](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2274). The solution is to replace `\usepackage{amsthm}` with `\usepackage[amsmath,amsthm,thmmarks]{ntheorem}` -- and you can drop the `\qedhere` completely.

Comment: I don't think you want it. You have a full stop and the QED symbol should be level to it. It's no different to the case of an integral, that extends below the baseline.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Enrico already mentioned, I wouldn't use a stop after the matrix. However, you can use the `\tag` amcro from `amsmath`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[width=7cm]{geometry} % Only for reducing space in this MWE 
\usepackage{amsmath} % For `bmatrix`
\usepackage{amsthm} % For `proof` environment
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
And this proof ends with
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}\\[-\normalbaselineskip]\tag*{\qedhere}
\end{align*}
\end{proof}
\noindent Text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This answer seemed to me the easiest and gives me an idea to solve another problem.

Answer (score 10):

Since you're using punctuation (which I agree with), the QED symbol should share the baseline with the punctuation.

Here's a trick that avoids using `ntheorem` (which I never use nor recommend); I also show *why* you shouldn't lower the tombstone.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[width=7cm]{geometry} % Only for reducing space in this MWE 
\usepackage{amsmath} % For `bmatrix`
\usepackage{amsthm} % For `proof` environment

\newenvironment{verticalhack}
  {\begin{array}[b]{@{}c@{}}\displaystyle}
  {\\\noalign{\hrule height0pt}\end{array}}

\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
And this proof ends with
\[
\begin{verticalhack}
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{verticalhack}\qedhere
\]
\end{proof}
\noindent Text
\begin{proof}
And this proof ends with
\[
\begin{verticalhack}
\int\limits_{\Gamma} f(x,y,z)\,dx\,dy\,dz.
\end{verticalhack}\qedhere
\]
\end{proof}
\noindent Text
\end{document}
```

[image]

The latter example makes no sense, does it? Well, the former example is just the same.

Comment: Why don't you use ntheorem package? Does it have some features you do not like, or is it flawed, so to say, in some way?

Comment: I find it quite rigid; `amsthm` is much easier to customize, maybe with the help of `thmtools`.

Comment: Is there a way to apply your solution to ams environments, like align? I have a problem, since in a book I write when I use \qedhere within align, the box is not flushed to the margin but is placed just after the dot ending the last line in a sequence of formulas.

Comment: @MadHatter I don't think you should use this approach to the placement of the tombstone to begin with. Are you using the `fleqn` option?

Comment: No, I am not using it.

Comment: @MadHatter Then this requires a new question.

Comment: OK. I'll post a new one if I do not handle the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with the `ntheorem` package:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{fourier}
    \usepackage{heuristica}

     \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage[thmmarks, amsmath, thref]{ntheorem}
    \usepackage{cleveref}

    \theoremstyle{plain}
    \theoremheaderfont{\bfseries}
    \theoremseparator{.}
    \theorembodyfont{\itshape}
    \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

    \theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
    \theoremheaderfont{\scshape}
    \theorembodyfont{\upshape}
    \theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\square}}
    \newtheorem{proof}{Proof}

    \theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\blacksquare}}
    \newtheorem{blackproof}{Proof}
    \begin{document}

    \begin{theorem}[Some theorem]\label{thm:some-theorem}
    This is an important theorem.
    \end{theorem}

    \begin{proof}[of \cref{thm:some-theorem}]
    This is a very important proof.
    \[ \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0
    \end{bmatrix}.\]
    \end{proof}

    \begin{blackproof}[of \cref{thm:some-theorem}]
    This is another very important proof.
    \begin{align*}
        a & = b\\ c & = d.
    \end{align*}
    \end{blackproof}

    \end{document}
```

[image]